# How to find absolute path to Katalon Recorder extension test suite for command line runner

Tags: command, line, runner, recorder, katalon

exploring Katalon recorder in chrome as an extention, but facing the below issue
Need to run below command in command Line runner

> kr-cli run   --report=
> Need to understand the pathToHtmlFile

I am confused about this one. Looking forward for help